# Apache2 Virtual Hosts Overriding One Another

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. I have been able to get subdomains to work on my server, running Ubuntu 10.04 Server. I am running like a Ubuntu recommends with the VirtualHost information in the sites-available/ folder. It was confusing at first how it worked, but after playing with it for over 8 hours things are making more sense.

My biggest problem I feel is I am missing something basic. I just don't know what it is. Here are my virtual host files.

sites-available/net.percent20.net

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName net.percent20.net
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/net.percent20.net/public_html/

    MonoServerPath net.percent20.net "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2"
    MonoDebug net.percent20.net true
    MonoSetEnv net.percent20.net MONO_IOMAP=all
    MonoApplications net.percent20.net "/:/srv/www/net.percent20.net/public_html"
    <Location "/">
            Allow from all
            Order allow,deny
            MonoSetServerAlias net.percent20.net
            SetHandler mono
            SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
            SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip dont-vary
    </Location>
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

sites-available/percent20.net

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName percent20.net
    ServerAlias www.percent20.net
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/percent20.net/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

sites-available/languagesamurai

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName languagesamurai.com
    ServerAlias www.languagesamurai.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/languagesamurai/
</VirtualHost>
```

The current problem I come up against is if I am trying to add a domain that isn't a subdomain it shows what is should be on net.percent20.net. However, net.percent20.net works too.

This is a real confusing problem and lack of knowledge about Apache on my part is a real hamper.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed I can provide that too.

Comment: Have you enabled the second site? sudo a2ensite languagesamurai

Comment: @LukeR use answer section so that percent20 can accept it

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to activate the site with:

```
sudo a2ensite languagesamurai
```

Comment: this should not be an answer, or should contain more then that...